# How to run custom Java under the classloader of a different Maven plugin

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I'm using android-maven-plugin to build and test an Android project.  I need to set the ddmlib timeout using the workaround in message #15 here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104305

So I created a Maven module which sets the timeout, and I'm running it in my test project with

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>ddm-timeout-fix</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.me.TimeoutFix</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This successfully executes, and it does so before ddmlib queries the timeout for the problematic operation.  The problem is that it is loaded by a different classloader than the android-maven-plugin, so android-maven-plugin (and thus ddmlib) can't see the change.

Is there any way to run the workaround using the same classloader that android-maven-plugin is running from?

Comment: Have you considered filing an issue or even a pull request that fixes this on the android maven plugin... I would merge it ;-)

Comment: @ManfredMoser I think setting android.adb.connectionTimeout will work in android-maven-plugin 4.4.1.  I am upgrading my projects to use that version (they were still on 3.x).